# What is the status of a married woman without a kesuba?

Tags: halacha, marriage, ketubah

If a married woman loses her [kesuba](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ketubah), may she continue to sleep with her husband? Is she still legally considered married? If she sleeps with someone else, has she committed adultery?

Answer (score 10):

She is definitely still married, so adultery remains absolutely forbidden. However, they must get a special new replacement kesuba written up before they may return to regular intimacy. ([Shulchan Aruch Even HaEzer 66:3](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9727&st=&pgnum=270))

Comment: Just to add a clarification to this excellent answer: replacing the kesuba is completely the husband's obligation. He must replace it as soon as possible, though they continue to have the same marital status until he does.