# Hanging the kesubah on the wall?

Tags: halacha, minhag, marriage, ketubah

I've heard from some people that there is a problem with hanging/displaying ones kesubah on the wall. Others have told me that it's good to display the kesubah as a reminder to the husband to fulfill his obligations to his wife. What's the best thing to do?

Answer (score 3):

There is a long history of creating beautiful ketubot that were displayed. I can only think of two issues where displaying it on a wall in the house could cause real problems:

1. The safekeeping of a ketubah is of extreme importance. The ketubah is required in the case of a couple ending a marriage, and so should always be in the safekeeping of the wife.
2. Issues of privacy could make the display inappropriate. Depending on the bride's case, matrachta (divorcee), geryuta (convert) or armalta (widow) is written instead of virgin. Additionally, a divorcee's dowry is written as 100 zuzim instead of the 200 written for a virgin bride. This is obviously sensitive information and the idea of guests being privy to it by its mere display does not seem worth the possible strife, regardless of the intended aesthetic/affirmative quality.

Comment: I know of couples who display it in the bedroom for these reasons.  (Displayed, because it's beautiful art and maybe for OP's reminder reason, but in a room where guests don't go.)

Comment: Keeping the Ketuba safe is important even during the marriage, as the husband and wife are forbidden to each other if she doesn't know that it is safe.

Comment: @DoubleAA, do you have a source for "...the husband and wife are forbidden to each other if she doesn't know that it is safe"?  I was under the impression that that's only the first night.  It is of vital importance that it be kept safe, but that is for the wife's protection, as I understand it, not for marital relations.

Comment: @SethJ http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/16331/759 Moreover it's not actually for her protection because even if she can't find her ketuba at the end of a marriage we assume she had one and pay her the money.

Comment: Does this mean it would be different if the kesuba were for a besula-virgin as there is no reason to keep it private because there is nothing embarrassing written in it? @Areh

Answer (score -1):

in Israel and maybe some other countries - the Rabbanut HaRashit should have a copy of the Ketubah. Usually this is their standard version, which is filled in at the same time as the fancy one, and should have the same content. This is to solve the issue of not having a Ketubah